# Compare two Arrays and replace Duplicates with values from a third array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['a','v','n','d','i','f'];

var array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];
```

Just starting to learn Javascript, I can't figure out how to compare the values of `array2` to those on `array1` and if so replace it with the corresponded array index from `array3`.

To turn it like this:

```
array2 = ['1','v','n','4','i','f'];
```

But also, it has to compare the values from array1 and array2 even if the index positions are different like this:

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['d','v','n','a','i','f'];
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: do you want to change `array2`?

Comment: Yes. But also, it has to compare the values from array1 and array2 even if the index positions are different like this:

var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['d','v','n','a','i','f'];

Sorry if im not been very clear...

Comment: please add the information to the question, because it is important.

Comment: You're right, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash table and check against. If the string is not included in the hash table, a replacement value is set for this element.

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'],
    array2 = ['d','v','n','a','i','f'],
    array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'],
    hash = Object.create(null);

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a] = true;
});

array2.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (hash[a]) {
        aa[i] = array3[i];
    }
});

console.log(array2);
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'],
    array2 = ['d','v','n','a','i','f'],
    array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];

array2.forEach((hash => (a, i, aa) => {
    if (hash.has(a)) {
        aa[i] = array3[i];
    }
})(new Set(array1)));

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: But what if `array1` is longer than `array2`

Comment: the question is *To turn it like this: `array2 = ['1','v','n','4','i','f'];`*

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to check the *duplicates* and create a new array - see demo below:

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['a','v','n','d','i','f'];

var array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];

var result = array2.reduce(function(p,c,i){
  if(array1.indexOf(c) !== -1) {
     p.push(array3[i]);
  } else {
     p.push(c);
  }
  return p;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` on array2 and see if current element is same as element in array1 with same index if it is return element from array3 with index of `i` else return current element or `e`

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var array2 = ['a', 'v', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'f'];

var array3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];

var result = array2.map(function(e, i) {
  return e == array1[i] ? array3[i] : e;
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
array2.map((v, i) => v === array1[i] ? array3[i] : v);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many forms, this is a basic form:

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['a','v','n','d','i','f'];
var array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];
var result = [];//define array of result
for(var i=0;i<array2.length;i++){//Iterate the array2
    if(array2[i] == array1[i])//Compare if array1 in index 'i' with array2 in index 'i'
        result[i] = array3[i];//if true put in result in index 'i' from array3
    else
        result[i] = array2[i];//else put in result in index 'i' from array2
}
console.log(result);//show in console the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some code that does what you ask:

```
    var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
    var array2 = ['a','v','n','d','i','f'];
    var array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];
    var biggerArrayLength = 0;

        if(array1.length > array2.length){
            biggerArrayLength = array1.length;
        }else{
            biggerArrayLength = array2.length;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < biggerArrayLength; i++){
            if(array1[i] == array2[i]){
                array2[i] = array3[i];
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceDuplicates(array1, array2, array3) {

    // array3 can't be smaller than array1!
    if (array3.length < array1.length) throw new Error('array3 < array1');

    // Loop through all the items in array1...
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

        // Check if the item in array2 matches...
        if (i < array2.length && array2[i] === array1[i]) {

            // And if it does replace array1's item with array3's item!
            array1[i] = array3[i];

        }
    }
}


var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = ['a','v','n','d','i','f'];
var array3 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];

replaceDuplicates(array1, array2, array3);

console.log(array1); // ['1','v','n','4','i','f']
```